# Application private directory on iOS with access to creation of files from Qt APIs

Tags: ios, iphone, qt, file, ipad

I am using **Qt app** on **iOS** & want to save files into **Application's private directory** so that other apps cannot access my files. Reading through the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), `/Documents` directory under data container looks to be the path to save my files which are private to app.

**Firstly** I chose to use `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)` which returned 
`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/123XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/Library/Application Support/MyApp`. But then I found that I could not create any files in there. Tried `/Documents` inside the App folder as well. But in vain.

**Secondly** I tried `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation)` which returned `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/123XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/Documents`. I am able to create & save my files here.

*On iOS, which is the correct path to create files which are meant to be private to the application ?

How can I get the path using Qt?*

The directory named with some ID as `123XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX`, Is this the application directory or is it `Library/Application Support/MyApp` inside the same directory ?

Comment: Have you tried `"./"`, the current working directory?  That how I do the same in Android.  Since the app is sandboxed, the directory that the app is launched may be inside the app file sandbox.

Comment: turns out that `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)` returns the application folder but I have to add `/Documents` to it on ios as I said. **But the most important learning** is that if the path doesnt exist, I have create it by using `QDir::mkpath` as is always the case with fresh installation. I was trying `mkdir` which was failing to create any folder. Seems like `QDir::mkpath` is better than using anything else to create folders. I am well able to save it in app sandbox on ios & android both cases now

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, for example I created a sqlite file. But the file that you will create can be every file you wants. In my example I need to create a sqlite file.

I solved like this:

```
    QString dbName = "mydb.sql";
    QString dbLocation;

       #ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
          dbLocation = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
       #endif

       #ifdef Q_OS_IOS
          dbLocation = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);
       #endif

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(dbLocation + "/" + dbName);
    qDebug() << db.database(dbLocation + "/" + dbName);
    qDebug() << db.databaseName();
```

Now you can save the file, I used DocumentsLocation to get a path, always works on iOS, but not work on Android, to be ready to Android you use another path: AppDataLocation.
In the documents location you can write/read/put and create files on iOS.
In the AppDataLocation location you can write/read/put and create files on Android.
Permission not denied in DocumentsLocation.